# Recursion - Declaring variable in the body or use it as a parameter?

Tags: c++, recursion

What is the difference between this recursive function:

```
int foo (int n,int sum)  
{
    if (n==0)  
        return sum;
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
    return foo(n-1,sum+temp);
}

int main()
{
    ...
    ...
    foo(n,0);
    ...
    ...
}
```

and this one:

```
int foo (int n,int sum, int temp)  
{
    if (n==0)  
        return sum;
    cin>>temp;
    return foo(n-1,sum+temp,temp);
}

int main()
{
    ...
    int temp;
    foo(n,0,temp);
    ...
    ...
}
```

which one is more efficient in the manner of space complexity? does they have any difference at all?
can we say as the recursive calls makes a copy of the parameters, declaring a variable in the function is the same as using it as a parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry I fixed it.

Comment: The second version is just stupid. Don't use function parameters as local variables! Absolutely nothing is gained.

Comment: I know it's stupid but I want to know which one is more efficient.

Comment: Declare your local parameters as local parameters.  Passing them in as arguments takes up some extra CPU cycles for no reason.  Declaring a local int parameter has zero cost in terms of CPU cycles.

Comment: @Amen, why do you think they are different? 3 ints per function call.

Comment: To optimize it, loop can be used instead of recursion.

Comment: I think that compiler may unroll the recursion and produce identical code here.

Comment: An optimizing compiler is also going to simply use registers for parameter passing and the local temp.

Comment: Actually, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions, on 64 bit Windows, passing temp as parameter is going to use less stack space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the memory consumption point of view a function parameter is identical to a local vartiable. I.e. there's no difference between the two variants form the point of view of memory consumption, aside from the fact that you introduced a completely unnecessary local variable in `main`.

However, the second variant might be less efficeint in therms of time, since at each level of recursion you pass the current value of `temp` down to the next level of recursion. That value is not used at all (the one received from `main` is not even initialized), meaning that any CPU efforts spent on passing it there are completely wasted.

Comment: +1--was just starting to write an answer that pointed to the possible difference in time used.

Comment: Passing the indeterminate value from `main` is pretty serious -- undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you AndreyT for the answer but would you explain about Rob K comment on the question?  
"Actually, according to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions, on 64 bit Windows, passing temp as parameter is going to use less stack space."